# Javascript Close button not works in Todo app

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I have made todo app but the close button not working.
2. I need when I click on close button than the that text is close.
3. If any can help me I shall be very thankful.
4. I have made todo app but the close button not working.
5. I need when I click on close button than the that text is close.
6. If any can help me I shall be very thankful.

```js
const todo = [];
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 const id = e.target.id;
 for(let i of todo) {
  if(i.id == id) {
   i.done = true;
  }
 }
 printTodos();
})

const printTodos = () => {
 ul.innerHTML = '';
 for(let i of todo) {
  ul.innerHTML += `<li id='${i.id}' class='${i.done ? 'done' : ''}'>${i.text}<button id='close'>x</button></li>`
  
 }
}
 


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const input = document.querySelector('input');
 todo.push({
  text: input.value,
  done: false,
  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
 });
 input.value = '';
 printTodos();

});
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.form {
  margin: 30px 300px;

}

input {
  padding: 13px 15px;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  font-size: 20px
}

.display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>todos</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sytl.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="info">
     <span class="total"></span>
     <span class="remaining"></span>
  </div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="add a todo" />
  </form>
   <div class="list">
    <ul></ul>
   </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is you repeating all your points in the list, the second is that your code generates each button with same  `id="close"` when ID's should be unique.

Comment: The button id is unique..

Comment: no, `li` 's `id`'s are unique, button is always close.

Comment: Change  `ul.innerHTML += \`<li id='${i.id}' class='${i.done ? 'done' : ''}'>${i.text}<button id='close-${i.id}'>x</button></li>\`` to make it unique

Comment: Yes, I got it thanks.,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const printTodos = () => {
    ul.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i of todo) {
        ul.innerHTML += `<li id='${i.id}_item' class='${i.done ? 'done' : ''}'>${i.text}<button id='${i.id}_close_btn' data-item-id='${i.id}'>x</button></li>`;
    }

    for (let i of todo) {
        document.getElementById(i.id+'_close_btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
           let itemId = this.getAttribute('data-item-id');
           let todoItem = todo.find(item => item.id == itemId);

           todoItem.done = true;

           printTodos();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry.. and now?

Comment: by the way it's not a good idea, to generate todo ids this way, because you will have duplicated ids.

Comment: yeah! I have check that it generate same ids. thanks for Help.